# Vlookup based off of resulting text of a formula

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am having an issue with a Vlookup formula.

the workbook contains 3 sheets.

I need to compare values from `E2:E867` on sheet 2 with the values from `C2:C867` on sheet 3 and return the value from sheet 3 column B on sheet 2.  this should be relatively straight forward except the values from `E2:E867` on sheet 2 are populate by another `Vlookup` formula so the `vlookup` I am writing is looking at the actual formula in `E2:E867` on sheet 2 instead of the resulting values in `E2:E867` on sheet 2.

how can I get the `vlookup` to compare the resulting values in `E2:E867` on sheet 2 in stead of the formulas resulting values in `E2:E867` on sheet 2.

formula that is used to populate `E2:E867`

```
=VLOOKUP($A489,'sheet 2'!$A$2:$L$867,7)
```

formula that is having issues

```
=VLOOKUP($E489,'sheet 3'!$C$2:$C$867,2)
```

it should return the value in column 2 from sheet 3 that matches the value of cell `E489`, but instead, when you step into the formula, it looks at the formula from `E2:E867` .

I know I may not be asking the question clearly, so please let me know if you need some clarification.

thank you.

Comment: The 2 in =VLOOKUP($E489,'sheet 3'!$C$2:$C$867,2) refers to the second column, yet you are only referencing a single column with 'sheet 3'!$C$2:$C$867

Comment: i change it to =VLOOKUP($E489,'sheet 3'!$A$2:$C$867,2) with the same results.  it is stepping into the vlookup that is being used to populate E489.  I need the vlookup to read the text from E489 instead of looking at the formula that was used to populate E489

Comment: It is not going to work with vlookup as Vlookup needs to have the lookup column on the left and the returned value column on the right.  You will need to use INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: So, now... you are looking the result from the formula in `E489` into `Sheet3!A2:A867`. If it finds a match in `Sheet3!A2:A867`, then it will return the value in Column `B` of `Sheet3`. You keep saying that it's not getting the value from the formula in E489, but it is. The problem seems to be that you might be misunderstanding how vlookup works.

Comment: your right, it is pulling something from E489 its pulling the vlookup formula used to populate E489, what I need it to do is pull the resulting text from E489

Comment: use this formula: `=INDEX('sheet 3'!B:B,MATCH($E489,'sheet 3'!C:C,0))`

Comment: Scott.  awesome thank you.  that does exactly what I needed.  I was just reading up on using the INDEX instead of vlookup.  thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit goes to Scott Craner - use this formula: =INDEX('sheet 3'!B:B,MATCH($E489,'sheet 3'!C:C,0)) – this was exactly what I needed.  Thank you Scott